# How can remove the background color for <application ../> in AndroidManifesh.xml in Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I find there is a background color for `<application ../>` section in AndroidManifesh.xml in Android Studio 3.2.1.You can see the following image.

How can I remove the background color?

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Move the cursor outside of that section?

Comment: Thanks! The same color when I move the cursor outside of that section

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the bulb next to the `<application>` tag and did what it suggested and the highlight disappeared. Basically, it asked to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` as a field in the  `manifest` tag as following (3rd line).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            package="package.name.here">
```